# LitElement: javascript function runs on repeat

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, lit-element

I have made a LitElement that is supposed to console log all users in a database. I do this with nodejs and mysql. I am able to get the users from the database and console.log them, but the script that fetches the data runs on repeat which it should not do. This is my LitElement.

```js
 export class AllUsers extends LitElement{
    static get properties(){
        return {
            users : {type : String},
            numberOfUsers : {type : Number},
            location : {type: Object} // Needed for vaadin-router with litElements
        }
    }
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.location = router.location
    }

    static styles = css`
    :host {
        display: block;
    }   
    `;

    render(){
        return html `
            <h1>ALL USERS</h1>
            ${this.getUsers()}
        `;
    }

    getUsers(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/getUsers', {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then(res =>{ res.json().then(data =>{
                    this.users = data
                    console.log(this.users)
                    this.numberOfUsers = this.users.length
                })
        }).catch((e) =>{
            throw Error(e)
        })
    }
}
customElements.define('all-users', AllUsers)
```

nodejs app

```js
app.get('/getUsers', function (req, res) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).send('Error in database operation.');
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
  });
});
```

What would have to be changed to fix this?

Comment: repeat before `fetch` is probably missing

Comment: It's because you execute an async function inside the template. You should consider checking out a tutorial such as https://open-wc.org/codelabs/intermediate/lit-html.html#0 that covers making async API requests, showing/using a loading state, and then rendering the data once the api request is successful. You would use `connectedCallback` as a point to determine whether to make the API call.

Comment: Thank you for that resource. It had a fix to my problem by using connectedCallback as you suggested. The function now only runs once, as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This template:

```
return html `
    <h1>ALL USERS</h1>
    ${this.getUsers()}`;
```

Renders the output of `this.getUsers()` into the template, but that's a `void`, so it basically just fires the function again each time it's rendered.

There are a couple of different approaches here - I'd recommend using `guard` and `until` to only get the users when some property changes, or adding a `ReactiveController` that fetches and caches users, but simplest is probably to just render the users and then kick off the script to get them.

Firstly change the template to render the users:

```
return html `
    <h1>ALL USERS</h1>
    ${this.users?.map(u => html`<span>User: ${u.name}</span>`)}`;
```

Then simplify your `getUsers` to just populate it (note this is also a lot simpler with `async`/`await`):

```
async getUsers() {
    if(this.users)
        return; // We already have users, don't get again

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/getUsers', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    this.users = await res.json();
    console.log(this.users);
    this.numberOfUsers = this.users?.length;
}
```

Then call `this.getUsers()` in either `firstUpdated` or `connectedCallback`.